# CGImageCreate making noise towards bottom of the image Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cgimage, cgimageref

I'm using `CGImageCreate` to create an image from a byte buffer (of `uint8_t`). The image seems to get noise towards the bottom though. Is there an alternate way to do this or am I doing something wrong using `CGImageCreate`?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Post some code and somebody should be able to help you out.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [CGImageCreate Test Pattern is not working (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864548/cgimagecreate-test-pattern-is-not-working-ios)?

Comment: Thanks guys, but my program ended up working because of Kurt Revis's post. Thanks Kurt!